# How do I translate reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)->hwndParent) to VB6?

Tags: c++, vb6

I neeed to convert a piece of code from C++ to VB6.

Specifically, this one:

```
reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)->hwndParent)
```

Can somebody tell me what this would look like in VB6?
I am not experienced enough in C++ to understand what exactely this does.

Thank you very much!

About the background of this question:

A control doesn't seem to have full Unicode support if it is used in Visual Basic 6. Why?
The forms, that Visual Basic 6 is creating, are ANSI windows. Therefore they force the control's underlying native treeview window class to use ANSI messages when communicating with the form. This breaks Unicode support in some situations. To work around this problem, the WM_NOTIFYFORMAT message must be reflected back to the control.
In Visual Basic, you must subclass the control's container window and send  WM_NOTIFYFORMAT back to the window that it was sent for. In C++, message reflection works similar.

```
LRESULT ExplorerTreeView::OnCreate(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& /*wasHandled*/)
{
    LRESULT lr = DefWindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);

    if(*this) {
        // this will keep the object alive if the client destroys the control window in an event handler
        AddRef();

        /* SysTreeView32 already sent a WM_NOTIFYFORMAT/NF_QUERY message to the parent window, but
           unfortunately our reflection object did not yet know where to reflect this message to. So we ask
           SysTreeView32 to send the message again. */
        SendMessage(WM_NOTIFYFORMAT, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)->hwndParent), NF_REQUERY);

        Raise_RecreatedControlWindow(HandleToLong(static_cast<HWND>(*this)));
    }
    return lr;
}
```

Comment: You are on difficult path. Only by sub classing and micromanaging all its default behaviours can this succeed. You would need to intercept all strings and keystrokes and turn them into byte arrays (VB does make this easy `A()= "MyCustomString"` (with `A()` defined as `byte` will give you a byte array containing Unicode characters). The form needs to be created with `CreateWindowsW` so the only way to make this work is create your own form (or Window as API calls it) and use only byte arrays as strings.

Comment: Because the controls create windows using `CreateWindowA` all string messages to the control will be converted from Unicode to ANSI by Windows (not VB6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just the handle of the form where the control resides, you can replace that code with `Me.hWnd`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you see what strange kind of SendMessage that is? I thought the first parameter should be a window handle, but the author is using a Windows Message...

Comment: `SendMessage` (and `DefWindowProc`) are probably methods of `ExplorerTreeView` class (probably) inherited from `CWnd` parent class so `hwnd` param to `::SendMessage` (i.e. global one) is current `m_hwnd` i.e. the member variable for the handle to this window.